# UIView reappear even after begin removed from superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I have a problem where if I remove subview from super view and then when I push to another VC and come back all the removed subview reappear in the view I have tried everything and checked my code if viewDidApper too.

[image]

```
//HERE IS HOW I ADD VIEWS

func addusers() {

    for user in 0...5 {
        let radarButton = PRButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: itemSize.width, height: itemSize.height+14))
        radarButton.profileButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "dummy-avatar.png"), for: UIControlState())
        radarButton.profileName.setTitle("test \(user)", for: .normal)

        repeat {
            let center = generateCenterPointInRadar()
            radarButton.center = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y)

        } while (itemFrameIntersectsInOtherItem(radarButton.frame))
        radarButton.profileButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapUser), for: .touchUpInside)
        radarButton.profileName?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapUser), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(radarButton)
        items.append(radarButton)
    }

}

//HERE IS HOW I REMOVE VIEWS
func removeAllUsers() {
    for view in self.subviews {
        if view is PRButton  {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    items.removeAll()

}
//Remove from superview
    override func removeFromSuperview() {

        UIView.beginAnimations("", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
        self.alpha = 0
        UIView.setAnimationDidStop(Selector(("callSuperRemoveFromSuperview")))
        UIView.commitAnimations()

    }

fileprivate func callSuperRemoveFromSuperview() {
    super.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the views aren't inside another view container?

Comment: @Edu I'm sure I have included a test project you can download and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to look at...

In `PRButton` you override `removeFromSuperview()` -- but your structure is incorrect and you never actually remove the view.

Replace it with this:

```
override func removeFromSuperview() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: ({
        self.alpha = 0.0
    }), completion: { _ in
        self.callSuperRemoveFromSuperview()
    })

}
```

You could also simply call `super.removeFromSuperview()` instead of your additional `self.callSuperRemoveFromSuperview()` function.

Get to know the `Debug View Hierarchy` feature... you would have seen that immediately.

Comment: Could he also simply call  super.removeFromSuperView() at the beginning?

Comment: That would lose the "fade-away" animation. He *could* also fix his `.setAnimationDidStop` selector... but the block format is generally considered the "way of the future" (depending on the opinion).

Comment: @DonMag Thanks fixed it I ill always use block format in feature that helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the test project.
I think I found the problem, it was at the `override func removeFromSuperview()`
I comment out it and edit the removeAllUsers()

```
func removeAllUsers() {
    for view in self.subviews {
        if view is PRButton  {
          UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
            view.alpha = 0
          }, completion: { (finished) in
            view.removeFromSuperview()
          })
        }
    }
    items.removeAll()

}
```

Now I don't see any duplicate users while I'm back to the `viewController`

Comment: Thanks, fixing removeFromSuperview() solved my problem